# Trying to install subversion for the first time

Tags: svn

I'd like to install subversion (svn) source control server on my local machine.
I already downloaded the server's binary project (subversion 1.6 I suppose) from 2 different vendors ([Callbnet](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/) and [SlikSvn](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download)), but in both cases I don't understand what are the commands to start and stop the server.

Do I have to download seperately apache server in order to run the SVN server on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easier to use [VISUALSVN SERVER](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/), if you are planning to install Subversion server on a Windows machine.

Comment: +1 - It's the perfect environment for a first time user. Or indeed an experienced user. :-)